# How to open an xml file in an android app

Tags: android, file, parsing, dom

I use a dom parser in android in order to parse an XML file.
Also, i use eclipse.

I do:

```
File file = new File("myfile.xml");
if(file!= null)
    Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG,"FILE OK");
else
    Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG,"FILE NOT OK!!!");
```

After the previous statement i get "**FILE OK**" in LogCat.

Then I would like to parse the "myfile.xml". The system can't find the file specified

My code is as following:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = builder.parse(file);
Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG," Before parsing"); 

if(doc != null)
  Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG," DOC is not null");
else
  Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG," DOC IS NULL!!!");
```

I get in LogCat:

```
 Before parsing
 W/System.err(2099): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /myfile.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I noticed that there is a '/' before myfile.xml and I can't understand where is the root
dir

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Where is the file?  Assets? xml? App's local storage?  SD card?

Comment: I have placed it in every possible location: src folder, project folder, assets folder in eclipse workspace.

Comment: I suggest you put it in the Assets directory of your project then do a search here on SO or using Google for how to copy files from assets to SD card (or to internal storage if you prefer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open the file from the assets folder:

```
 InputStream inStream = getActivity().getAssets().open("myfile.xml");
```

From the external storage (SD):

```
File toPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory();
File xmlFile = new File(toPath, "myfile.xml");
```

From the app's local storage:

```
FileInputStream inFile = mAppActivity.openFileInput("myfile.xml");
```

There are many other methods in the [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class for directories and files.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I chose your 1st solution and I did:`InputStream inStream = this.getAssets().open("myfile.xml");` , I used **this** instead of getActivity(), thanks